# Redirecionar para outra aba o PDF

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, dompdf

Olá, preciso de um help!
Meu projeto atual precisa de gerar um relatório da uma tabela, ótimo fiz com o DomPDF, a minha duvida é como eu faço para o pdf abrir em outra aba e não na aba atual. A versão do laravel é a 5.5. Desde já muito obrigada. :)

```
    public function pdfexport($id)
{
    //export PDF from students table
    $student = Student::find($id);
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('student.pdf', ['student'=> $student])->setPaper('a4', 'portrait');
    $fileName = $student->name.date("dmy");

    return $pdf->stream($fileName.'.pdf');
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ola, na sua view:

```
<a href="{{route("pdfexport")}}" target="_blank" > visualizar pdf </a>
```

e na rota:

```
Route::get('/pdf', 'YourController@pdfStream')->name('pdfexport');
```

Comment: Obrigada, foi tão simples e eu tinha me esquecido kkk

Answer (score 0):

Acho que a melhor alternativa é você da um target no seu formulário..segue o exemplo:

```
<form method="POST" action="suaaction" target="_blank">
```

Ouuu, poderia fazer utilizando `window.open("SUAURL);`

Conforme foi informado nessa issue(https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/419)

Comment: Muito obrigada pela resposta! :)